# Per day limit on number of GCM requests per day

Tags: max, limit, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM server. I have gone through google and GCM official docs. But I am not able to know about the number of messages or requests that can be made per day against an API key.

Is there is any limit on number of messages that can be send to or from android apps and Third party application server using GCM.

Thanks and advance.